# How to use the keyvalue pipe of Angular 6.1 and specify the displayed keyvalue pairs?

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe, angular6

**The Struggle**
I'm displaying key value pairs using the Angular 6 keyvalue pipe. This object has multiple keys, how do I display only specific keyvalue pairs (multiple)?

The data exists out of objects. I've tried to use "package.value.package_name", "package.value['package_name']"

**Code**

```
<div *ngFor="let function of functionTreeList | keyvalue">
   Key 1: <b>{{function.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{function.value}}</b>
   <p *ngFor="let package of function.value | keyvalue">
      Key 2: <b>{{package.key}}</b> and Value: <b>{{package.value}}</b>
   </p>
</div>
```

**Given result**:

Key 1: 0 and Value: [object Object]

Key 2: modules and Value: [object Object]

Key 2: package_id and Value: 1

Key 2: package_name and Value: Package 1

Key 1: 1 and Value: [object Object]

Key 2: modules and Value: [object Object],[object Object]

Key 2: package_id and Value: 2

Key 2: package_name and Value: Package 2

**Desired result**

Desired result is to exclude the visible package_id and put this in Paragraph or Div outside the element. Also making the modules keyvalue pair invisible.

Comment: Do you have a sample stackblitz to work with? If not would you please consider creating it so that it could be looked into?

Comment: @SiddAjmera https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-keyvaluepipe-demo-762uea

Comment: Seems to work in your blitz ...

Comment: Everything shows indeed, but how do I take control over the displayed key/value pairs to make them (in)visible?

Comment: you can use an *ngIf in a ng-container. Sorry I don't know if help your forked stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-keyvaluepipe-demo-bhduw9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @Eliseo Yes that is it! Please post it as an answer, I'll check it as correct